# AFNetworking equivalent of curl statement

Tags: objective-c, curl, nsdictionary, elasticsearch, afnetworking

I attempting to query a hosted instance of elasticsearch (Searchbox.io) using AFNetworking. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the syntax working properly. For example, the following statement using curl works just fine and returns exactly what I would expect.

```
curl -XGET 'http://api.searchbox.io/api-key/<MYAPIKEY>/<MYINDEX/_search' -d '{"query" : {"query_string" : {"query" : "searchTerm"}}}'
```

I get back the docs from Searchbox.io that contain "searchTerm". Super. However, when I try to implement the same in AFNetworking, the Searchbox.io API returns a 500 error, noting "Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [*na*]]]; nested" Below is the call in my subclass of the AFHTTPClient.

```
NSDictionary *searchDict = @{@"query":@{@"query_string":@{@"query":@"searchTerm"}}};

[self getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_search"]
    parameters:searchDict
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
       NSLog(@"Search Results: \n\n %@", responseObject);
   }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Search Error: %@", error);
   }
}];
```

FYI - the subclassed AFHTTPClient is set with the following statements prior to this call. The subclassed AFHTTPClient client is working properly and the baseURL is set correctly.

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
```

To my newbie eyes, it looks like AFNetworking is handling the searchDict differently than the literal in the curl statement. To summarize, what would be the equivalent of the curl statement above, as implemented in AFNetworking? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around a bit more, I was able to get it to work by:

- Pulling the latest rev of AFNetworking (1.3.1)
- Changing the initWithBaseURL method of my AFHTTPClient subclass to the code below
- Importing "AFJSONRequestOperation.h" into my AFHTTPClient subclass
- Using the postPath:parameters:success:failure method to hit the API

  ```
  [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
  [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
  [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
  ```

It is beyond me as to why the curl statement would be -XGET and the AFNetworking method would be a POST. Surely my misunderstanding.